# Node-red beginners issue. Connection failed to broker: mqtt://

Tags: connection, mqtt, node-red

I am trying to get started with Node-red on a Windows 10 machine. The end goal is to use my PC as a server to an ESP8266:

[image: my test flow]

My problem: I cant get the broker to connect.

My output:

## Welcome to Node-RED

```
24 Jun 13:55:28 - [info] Node-RED version: v3.0.2
24 Jun 13:55:28 - [info] Node.js  version: v18.16.0
24 Jun 13:55:28 - [info] Windows_NT 10.0.19044 x64 LE
24 Jun 13:55:30 - [info] Loading palette nodes
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] Settings file  : C:\Users\XXX\.node-red\settings.js
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] User directory : \Users\XXX\.node-red
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] Flows file     : \Users\XXX\.node-red\flows.json
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [warn] Using unencrypted credentials
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] Starting flows
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] Started flows
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] [mqtt-broker:da0f72b473b07905] Connection failed to broker:   mqtt://localhost:1883
24 Jun 13:55:32 - [info] [mqtt-broker:5e230a1f15702218] Connection failed to broker: mqtt://location.host:1883
24 Jun 13:55:34 - [info] [mqtt-broker:26b3604d9443e4fb] Connection failed to broker: mqtt://192.168.2.60:1883
```

(I also has a another flow in the background trying to make the server available to an ESP8266, hence the 192.168.2.60:1883 connection attempt)

What am I missing? Why is it not connecting?

Thanks!

I have tryied to set both the mqtt in/out server to same address localhost:1883 or location.host:1883 or 127.0.0.1:1883. Have tried outer port numbers too.

I tried to disable my firewall.

I have found outers with similar problems and follows their solutions, without success.

Tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amA5OaXXCJo

Comment: Are you actually running a MQTT broker? Node-RED doesn't have one built in (though there is a node to add one)

Comment: Probably not. I have not installed anything extra apart from Node Red. 

After your reply I tried to install HiveMQ (and upgrade my Java 8 to Java 11).
I still didn´t manage to connect to the mqtt-broker on 127.0.0.1:1883 or 127.0.0.1:8080.

How do I successfully install a broker in the simplest way?

Thanks!

Comment: That is now a totally separate question, there are plenty of examples online (and other questions on SO), you need to try and you can always ask a new question supplying a **LOT** more detail about what you've tried, what you've done to debug and how it's not working.

Comment: In HiveMQ output window I saw "Started TCP Listener on address 0.0.0.0 and on port 1883. So I typed in those values in my mqtt in/out in the test flow pictured above.
And now it works, not sure how to get this working with the ESP8266 via WiFi, but that will be yet another question.

Thank you for for time hardillb!